# How can I run an assertion test after a certain amount of simulated time using jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Say I have a Component that renders a simple div containing an integer that starts at 0 and ticks up 1 every second. So after 5 seconds, the component should render "5" and after 30 seconds, it should render "30" and so on. If I wanted to test this component and make sure its rendering what it should after 5 seconds, I might write something like this.

```
it('should render <5> after 5 seconds', () => {
  const time = mount(<Timer/>)
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(time.text()).toEqual('5')
  }, 5000)
})
```

However, this doesn't work as the test never actually runs the expect and returns a pass regardless of anything. And even if it did work, using a timeout like this would be extremely inefficient as the test would have to wait 5 seconds. And what if I wanted to simulate an even larger amount of time? After doing some searching, I found jest actually has a [timer mock](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/timer-mocks.html) but I can't seem to figure out how to implement it for this case. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the module code that use the timer?

Answer (score 2):

in order for Jest to know that your test is async, you need to either: 1) return a Promise, or 2) declare an argument in the test callback, like so:

```
it('should render <5> after 5 seconds', done => {
  // test stuff
});
```

source: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html

To get your test working:

```
it('should render <5> after 5 seconds', done => {
  jest.useFakeTimers(); // this must be called before any async things happen

  const time = mount(<Timer/>);

  setTimeout(() => {
    // Note the placement of this try/catch is important.
    // You'd think it could be placed most anywhere, but nope...
    try {
      // If this assertion fails, an err is thrown.
      // If we do not catch()...done.fail(e) it,
      // then this test will take jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL (5s unless you override)
      // and then fail with an unhelpful message.
      expect(time.text()).toEqual('5');
      done();
    } catch(e) {
      done.fail(e);
    }
  }, 5000);
  jest.runTimersToTime(5000); // This basically fast forwards 5s.
});
```

Comment: These try/catch get cumbersome to write, so I've made some test utils I hope to publish soon.  In addition to many other things, it could shorten setTimeout()'s callback body to:

`tf.finish(done, () => expect(time.text()).toEqual('3'));`

Let me know if you're interested, and I'll work on getting that published!

Answer (score 0):

You must call `jest.useFakeTimers();` before `require´ your component to mock setTimeout.

> Here we enable fake timers by calling jest.useFakeTimers();. This
>   mocks out setTimeout and other timer functions with mock functions.

And to test async workflows [Jest documentation says](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#basic-testing) you have to return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for each 'it' function callback.

> To test an asynchronous function, just return a promise from it. When
>   running tests, Jest will wait for the promise to resolve before
>   letting the test complete. You can also return a promise from
>   beforeEach, afterEach, beforeAll or afterAll functions. For example,
>   let's say fetchBeverageList() returns a promise that is supposed to
>   resolve to a list that has lemon in it. You can test this with:

---

So you can write something like:

```
it('should render <5> after 5 seconds', () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  //only after that, require your componenet
  let Timer = require('./timer');
  const time = mount(<Timer/>);
  jest.runAllTimers();
  expect(setTimeout.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
  expect(setTimeout.mock.calls[0][1]).toBe(5000);
  expect(time.text()).toEqual('5');
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I'm still not sure how the promise should look when the function that's asynchronous is the expect call itself.

Comment: You wont need as your test will run synchronous if you mock settimeout. I wrote two answers because you made two questions :)

Comment: Thanks again! I tried this but I get the error "Ran 100000 timers and there are still more! Assuming we've hit an infinite recursion and bailing out..." Maybe this is because the Timer component has an interval that runs every 1000ms?

Comment: "Maybe this is because the Timer component has an interval that runs every 1000ms?" Exactly!  That is why for combinations of setTimeout/setInterval, I generally prefer jest.runTimersToTime(), as in my answer.